# OS X App Development Framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've noticed a trend with some OS X apps lately. The official Twitter client, Sparrow and even GitHub for Mac seem to have a lot of similarity.

[image]

Do they use a framework that provides those elements?  And if so, what's it called and where I can get more information?

Comment: Look in the `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks` folder and see if their are any similarities

Comment: @ief2 - That's a great idea. I never thought about doing that.

Comment: It turns out that the Framework I'm looking for is called TwUI, it's developed by Twitter and available at [https://github.com/twitter/twui](https://github.com/twitter/twui).

Comment: Also, TwUI is about to get a lot more awesome: https://github.com/blog/1133-twitter-github-twui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter & Github use the [TwUI](https://github.com/twitter/twui) and [Chameleon](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon) Frameworks. The Sparrow mail app uses its own Core Animation UI Framework. IIRC then the Github for Mac devs were removing Chameleon and actually just going all TwUI.

TwUI brings a UI to OS X that is similar in many ways to UIKit, in that it was built to be used with Core Animation from the start.

The Chameleon Project actually brings UIKit API's directly to OS X. So in theory your special views built on UIKit should just work on OS X. The Twitterrific twitter client actually is an example of a Chameleon only app.

Comment: I already answered my own question but I appreciate the longer and more detailed answer.